# How comes ping to `1.1.1.1` is only 3ms where ping to `8.8.8.8` is 26ms?

Tags: dns

How comes ping to `1.1.1.1` is only 3ms where ping to `8.8.8.8` is 26ms?

```
PS C:\Users\0x90> ping 1.1.1.1

Pinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 1.1.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 4ms, Average = 3ms
Control-C
PS C:\Users\0x90> ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=55
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=55
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=55

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 26ms, Maximum = 27ms, Average = 26ms
Control-C
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be well served to do a traceroute to establish how your computer gets to each of these systems.   It does make sense though - the whole idea of multiple DNS servers is for redundancy, thus having them both situated in the same place - which you would expect to get the same latency - reduces their reliability.

8.8.8.8 is one of Googles nameservers, and is thus located as close to you as Googel recons is practical - 26ms is not far.

1.1.1.1 is very close to you.  The "legitimate" owner of this IP address is Cloudflare, and it is also possible that they have deployed a DNS server reachable by you at a well connected peering exchange in the same city - and close to, or in your ISP.

Comment: Could you share results from your system?

Comment: Both about 26ms from my colo box in NZ - but using 2 different carriers between NZ and Aussie.  About 1.3ms from my singapore servers, slightly different routes via sgix.

Comment: A more interesting result from a connection I have in Melbourne.  The latencies are all over the place, but 8.8.8.8 averages 45ms over 9 hops, 1.1.1.1 averages 29ms over 6 hops.

Comment: Just observing your pings - note the TTLs to 1.1.1.1 are 64, while 55 to 8.8.8.8 - this indicates 9 more hops to get to Googles servers - and probably that the router you are connecting to is offering dns for 1.1.1.1????